# 15" Macbook Pro: Radeon 555 or Radeon 560?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, performance, graphics, gpu

How different is Radeon 555 and Radeon 560 in the 15-inch Macbook Pro 2017? Are there any notable differences between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Introduction**
I think we need to agree that both of these graphics cards are the best they have ever been in a MacBook Pro. Naturally, the type of card you require is heavily dependent on the work you plan to do with the MacBook Pro (you didn't mention it). If you don't yet own one of the devices and are simply doing some research before you buy (as one should), you may find the next generation (releasing around June 2018) may be a better alternative - ahh, when will the time ever be right!?

**Notable Differences**

- The *AMD Radeon Pro 560* has twice the memory of the *AMD Radeon Pro 555* (*4GB* vs *2GB* respectively).
- The *AMD Radeon Pro 560* has about 10% greater Clock Speed than its rival (*925 MHz* vs *850 MHz* respectively).
- The *AMD Radeon Pro 560* has around 25% lower thermal design power (TDP) (*75W* vs *100W* respectively, lower is better).

**Reports**
There are GPU benchmarking sites like [GPUBoss](http://gpuboss.com/gpus/Radeon-Pro-560-vs-Radeon-Pro-555) and [Notebook Check](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Radeon-Pro-555-vs-Radeon-Pro-560_8064_8066.247598.0.html) if you are interested in further reads. Otherwise the difference is next to none.

Comment: The shopper’s tale of woe : always a better offer after you bought it !

Comment: So true!! @SolarMike